# How do I initialize a composed struct in Go?

Tags: go

Let's say I have a struct with another struct embedded in it.

```
type Base struct {
    ID string
}

type Child struct {
    Base
    a int
    b int
}
```

When I go to initialize `Child`, I can't initialize the `ID` field directly.

```
// unknown field 'ID' in struct literal of type Child
child := Child{ ID: id, a: a, b: b }
```

I instead have to initialize the ID field separately.

```
child := Child{ a: 23, b: 42 }
child.ID = "foo"
```

This would seem to violate encapsulation. The user of Child has to know there's something different about the ID field. If I later moved a public field into an embedded struct, that might break initialization.

I could write a `NewFoo()` method for every struct and hope everyone uses that, but ***is there a way to use the struct literal safely with embedded structs that doesn't reveal some of the fields are embedded?*** Or am I applying the wrong pattern here?

Comment: I really feel like there should be github issue for this. I feel like the syntactic sugar on getters (mentioned in [@CeriseLimón's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123399/how-do-i-initialize-a-composed-struct-in-go/44123416?noredirect=1#comment75266036_44123416)) _really_ should also be applied to the setters as well. The way it is now not only makes the code ugly, but requires the user of a class to be far to intimately familiar with the inheritance/hierarchy of the class in order to use it.

Answer (score 54):

Use nested [composite literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals) to initialize a value in a single expression:

```
child := Child{Base: Base{ID: id}, a: a, b: b}
```

[Go issue 9859](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9859) proposes a change to make composite literals consistent with field access for embedded types.  This change will allow the `Child{ ID: id, a: a, b: b }` expression from the question.

Embedded types do not provide encapsulation in the sense that the feature does not restrict direct access the embedded type.  An application can directly access `child.Base.ID` in addition to using `child.ID`.

Comment: While `child.ID` hides that `ID` is embedded, the initializer does not? What an odd oversight. If I want initialization encapsulation I need to write my own `New` functions?

Comment: Field promotion on embedded fields is syntactic sugar. The feature does not provide encapsulation.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't provide encapsulation?

Comment: @CeriseLimón, I think Schwern's point was that the syntactic sugar exists on the "getter", but not on the initializer. It's inconsistent.