# How do I omit a struct field *only* when marshalling, but keep it when unmarshalling?

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a User struct with a password field. When I'm creating a user (or udpating with a new password) via POSTed JSON, I want to accept/unmarshal the password field into my object, but whenever I *return* a user, I want to omit the password field. Below is the best I've been able to come up with so far. It works, but it requires a *lot* of duplication around the field names that I'd like to eliminate (right now, if I add a new field like `FirstName`, I have to add that in 3 separate places).

**How do I do this better *while still honoring the `json` tags on the struct*?**

```
func main() {
    origJson := []byte(`{"id":"1","username":"Chad","pwd":"sillypants"}`)
    fmt.Println("Original:     " + string(origJson))

    var unmarshalled User
    json.Unmarshal(origJson, &unmarshalled)
    fmt.Printf("Unmarshalled: %+v\n", unmarshalled)

    marshalled, _ := json.Marshal(unmarshalled)
    fmt.Println("ReMarshalled: " + string(marshalled))
}

type User struct {
    Id       string `json:"id"`
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"pwd"`
}

type SafeUser struct {
    Id       string `json:"id"`
    Username string `json:"username"`
}

func (u User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    safeUser := SafeUser{
        Id      : u.Id,
        Username: u.Username,
    }

    return json.Marshal(safeUser)
}
```

[Try it](https://play.golang.org/p/cENnVHqZe8) on the Go Playground

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue but came across [this article](http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/).

The idea is to use embedding and an anonymous struct to override fields.

```
func (u User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type Alias User
    safeUser := struct {
        Password string `json:"pwd,omitempty"`
        Alias
    }{
        // Leave out the password so that it is empty
        Alias: Alias(u),
    }

    return json.Marshal(safeUser)
}
```

[Try it](https://play.golang.org/p/RfZ_Svnwov)

The Alias helps prevent an infinite loop while marshalling.

Please note that you have to maintain the same JSON field name for the override to work.

Comment: Oh, this is perfect! And the alias is locally scoped inside the marshalling function, so it's not seen or accessible anywhere else, making it totally transparent. Nice work!

Answer (score 6):

Take advantage of [embedded structs](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding). Define a User, and embed that in an UnsafeUser which adds the password field (and anything else, like payment info).

```
type User struct {
    Id       string `json:"id"`
    Username string `json:"username"`
}

type UnsafeUser struct {
    User
    Password string `json:"pwd"`
}
```

(It's better to make things safe by default and declare what is unsafe, like [Go's unsafe pacakge](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/).)

Then you can extract the User from within the UnsafeUser without having to know and copy all the fields.

```
func (uu UnsafeUser) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(uu.User)
}

$ go run ~/tmp/test.go
Original:     {"id":"1","username":"Chad","pwd":"sillypants"}
Unmarshalled: {User:{Id:1 Username:Chad} Password:sillypants}
ReMarshalled: {"id":"1","username":"Chad"}
```

Note how you can see the User struct embedded within the unmarshalled UnsafeUser.

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely better than what I had! However, the problem I see with this is when manually instantiating a new `UnsafeUser`... `myUser := UnsafeUser{Id: "1", Username: "foo", Password: "bar"}` doesn't work, which means now my code has to use `myUser := UnsafeUser{SafeUser: SafeUser{Id: "1", Username: "foo"}, Password: "bar"}` which is just... terrible. Is there any way around that? Ideally, I'd like 1 of those classes to be entirely transparent.

Comment: @KOGI Yup, [I hit that problem myself yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123399/how-do-i-initialize-a-composed-struct-in-go/44123416?noredirect=1#comment75266036_44123416).